# Using Facebook Open Graph Stories, can I post multiple photos as part of the object?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting an Open Graph story from my iOS app.  So far everything is working great, but I want to extend the post beyond the vanilla implementation and I'm having trouble finding any documentation for the things I want to try.  For now, I want to just add more than one photo to a story post.  Here's the functioning code I have currently:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *fbphoto = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
fbphoto.image = newImage;
fbphoto.userGenerated = YES;

//Harvest Photo Action
//
NSString *typeKey = self.mapViewEngine.event.facebookAnimalORM.Name;
NSString *type = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", kFacebookNamespace, typeKey];
NSString *actionType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", kFacebookNamespace, kFacebookHarvestAction];

NSDictionary *properties = @{
@"og:type": type,
@"og:title": @"Harvest Photo",
@"og:description": @"Harvest photo post.",
@"og:url": self.mapViewEngine.event.facebookAnimalORM.Details,
@"og:image": @[fbphoto]
};
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = actionType;
[action setObject:object forKey:typeKey];

FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = typeKey;

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self.mapViewEngine.mapVC
withContent:content
delegate:self];
```

So far I have tried to include an additional `@"og:image"` tag in the properties dictionary, but Facebook only accepted the first key/value pair.  I also tried adding a second photo to the `@"og:image"` array value but that broke the code and the post just never made it to my timeline.

I'm hoping the Facebook documentation is just weak sauce and I'm missing the answer, but maybe this is just impossible?  Or is there a way to extend the basic Open Graph functionality I'm not seeing?

Comment: It is not currently possible to make posts containing multiple images via API.

Comment: Is there a method outside of using the API?

Comment: That is your only valid alternative without using their API.

Comment: It just seems odd to me that the iOS SDK can't do it when the object API allows it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api

Comment: I don’t think that uploading multiple images via the Object API will get you a story that actually _displays_ multiple images – that is just meant as a way to provide different image resolutions, from which Facebook will then pick the one best suited for the current display situation. ([Quote](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api#objectapi-images-multiple-images): _“This is useful because different types of stories require different resolution images, depending on the device the viewer is using.”_)